# Is it possible to change workflow primary entity in Dynamics CRM 365?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-365

I have created a workflow in Dynamics 365 and accidentally had set the primary entity to Contract instead of Contact. Is it possible to change it without recreating?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in another forum, so, just for the records, it's not possible. Only solution is to delete and recreate.

Comment: Yep it's a huge pain :)